# How do I add a comment to someone else's answer

Tags: discussion

I'd like to say thanks as well on answering an important question on this site. [Answered Here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/62099/how-to-completely-disable-password-saving-in-safari?answertab=active#tab-top)

I don't know how to add a comment underneath the answer's comments.

*Am I out of luck****?***

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the time you asked this question, you had [28 reputation points with these privileges](https://apple.stackexchange.com/privileges/user/17156). You can always comment on your own posts, but to [comment on other people's posts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment), you need 50 reputation points.

However, "me too" and "thanks" posts are unnecessary altogether on this site. Once someone has 15 reputation points, they can say thank you the Stack Exchange way: if you find an answer helpful, you can click the up arrow next to a post to say "thank you" or that you agree. This is called [voting up](https://apple.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up), and it's the [thing to do](http://apple.blogoverflow.com/2012/03/vote-vote-vote/) if you find an answer helpful.